# Why can clients send encrypted data before the server sends the change cipher spec in TLS1.2？

Tags: ssl, protocols, tls1.2, handshake

I was observing the handshaking process of tls1.2 and found that in many implementations of tls1.2, there are cases where the client sends the application data after sending the change cipher spec without waiting for the server to send the change cipher spec, why is that?[image]

I tried searching the web for the role of the change cipher spec, it should be followed immediately by the finished message, which is used to validate the preamble handshake message, but the size of the finished message is related to the cipher suite, and the cipher suite in the picture is TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 , and its size is 40, which is located in the Encrypted Handshake Message, but I don't know the next packet--application data is for what?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. [RFC 2246 #7.1 Change Cipher Spec Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2246#section-7.1) says nothing about waiting for the incoming `ChangeCipherSpec` message before sending encrypted data.